# Which operations on Scala parallel collections are parallelized?

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

It seems like when I invoke `map` on a parallel list, the operation runs in parallel, but when I do `filter` on that list, the operation runs strictly sequentially. So to make `filter` parallel, I first do map to (A,Boolean), then filter those tuples, and map all back again. It feels not very convenient.

So I am interested - which operations on parallel collections are parallelized and which are not?

Comment: [A Generic Parallel Collection Framework](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/150220/files/pc.pdf)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no parallel lists. Calling `par` on a `List` converts the `List` into the default parallel immutable sequence - a `ParVector`. This conversion proceeds sequentially. Both the `filter` and the `map` should then be parallel.

```
scala> import scala.collection._
import scala.collection._

scala> List(1, 2, 3).par.filter { x => println(Thread.currentThread); x > 0 }
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0,5,main]
res0: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[Int] = ParVector(1, 2, 3)
```

Perhaps you've concluded that the `filter` is not parallel, because you've measured both the conversion time and the `filter` time.

Some operations not parallelized currently: `sort*` variants, `indexOfSlice`.